# Installing Ubuntu on a Windows 11

Tags: virtualbox

I've been trying all day to install Ubuntu, Linux and VirtualBox on my Windows 11 Laptop and nothing is working. I have Anaconda and I can use Spyder. But as far as trying to set up a virtual machine, I'm completely lost. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly have you done so far and what exactly is the problem you are experiencing? Please edit your question and include more context and details. If you've been trying all day surely there's more details you can share.  Are you aware that there is an [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox) that walks you through everything you need to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out WSL

Here is a method to Install Linux on Windows with WSL in the microsoft docs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install